# Logging Stopped in Websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

The Websphere protal 6.1 was logging normally

[WAS_HOME]\profiles[PROFILE_NAME]\logs[SERVER_NAME]\

But when I tried to clear the content of the log file to clear old logs, WebSphere log to this file anymore and the file is always blank, knowing that i cleared the content of the old log file and didn't remove the the file itself so i don't think it would be a permission problem.

Thanks

Yehia

Comment: Does it still fail to log even after a server restart? In general, wouldn't suggest modifying log files that are currently in use by WAS. If you want to limit the size of your log files, consider configuring the log file maximum size through WAS instead.

Comment: How are you clearing the content? And does the log file just cease to be written until you restart the server, or is it no longer written even after restart? I'm assuming because of your path separators that you're on Windows?

Comment: it's no longer written after restart, what i did is opened the log file, Select All + delete, and saved the file

Comment: Which file contents are you deleting (e.g. SystemOut.log)? Also, what is your OS? Are you deleting the contents while the server is stopped or started? I tried deleting the contents of the SystemOut.log while the server was stopped, and then restarted the server, and the contents were written as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to cross check the configuration in WAS admin console whether if it is mapped to the proper location as expected. Because the scenario of yours works fine with my environment.

Console -> Troubleshooting->Logs and Trace